# how to access ABRecordRef value in a class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

this is my code to access contact details from device.
when i try to use the ABRecordRef value in another class it turn to crash in my program so please help me to solve this

enter code here

```
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
            CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                                                       kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                                                       people
                                                                       );
            CFArraySortValues(
                              peopleMutable,
                              CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
                              (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
                              (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering()
                              );

arrTemp1=(NSMutableArray *)CFBridgingRelease(peopleMutable);


for (int i=0;i<[arrTemp1 count];i++)
{
    allUsers = [[AllUsers alloc]init];
    allUsers.person=(__bridge ABRecordRef)(arrTemp1[i]);
}
```

---

```
@interface AllUsers : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,assign)  ABRecordRef  person;
@end
```

when i try to access the person value in another class then it turn to crash

```
AllUsers *currentUser;
ABRecordRef  personImageRef = currentUser.person;
NSLog(@"image ref -- %@",currentUser.person);
```

please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Edit question with Crash Report?

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you property made is `assign` make it `strong` and try and please let me know.

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly)  ABRecordRef  person;
```

Comment: @property (nonatomic,strong)  ABRecordRef  person; when i use this line of code then there is an error message showing .."property with retain(or strong) attribute must be of object type"

Comment: use * sign before person like @property (nonatomic,strong)  ABRecordRef  *person; Please dnt forget to give vote and accept the answer if this solves your question.

Comment: please look in to it http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/90251-having-abrecordref-as-property.html    and that should be * sorry for that , or please paste your error so that i can help you.